# Suffers from -> tends to?

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, dictionaries

Does "suffer from" have the meaning of "tend to"?

I looked up the Collins dictionary, and found that "suffer from" can mean "given to", which means "tend to".

E.g. A chemical element suffers from being a solid~ precursor. 
In the above sentence, Does "suffers from" mean "tend to"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What on earth does your example mean? What is a solid~precursor? A precursor of a solid or a precursor in the solid state? How can an element be a precursor? And in what context is this a disadvantage?  If this is a quotation from an external source, please cite it.

Comment: Words that are used synonymously are never completely identical, and it's even less likely that just because A is (sometimes) synonymous with B, and B is (sometimes) synonymous with C, that A can be synonymous with C.

Comment: sorry for the inappropriate example! I just can't cite or fully write a sentence since it can't be disclosed online (patent thing). I just wanted to know whether "suffer from" can mean "tend to" since I found out that "'suffer from' means 'given to' in Collins Dictionary. The original example was more like: "some chemical composition suffers from being a soild,~ precursor".

Answer (score 1):

They are not quite the same:

> Tends to

This just indicates that there is a tendency for something to happen.
*The shop tends to close early on a Saturday*

> Suffers from

This implies that not only is there a tendency, but that there is a negative impact.
*Dave suffers from migraines*

Comment: thanks for the comment.